# \begin{flalign*} equation alignment

Tags: flalign

How can I align the blue texts?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
&\color{red}f:x^2+y^2=4,\qquad \color{blue}f(3)=2&\\
&\color{red}g:x^2-y^2=2,\qquad \color{blue}g(4)=1&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you in two-column mode?

Comment: No. I drew the black lines later @Bernard

Comment: Why using flalign for such a small equation, in this case?

Comment: When I use align, the equation starts from the middle. I used flalign because I wanted the equation to start from the left @Bernard

Comment: using an alignment and not specifying any alignment points other than the leftmost edges is very weird though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, which works somewhat like `subequations`, and the `alignat*` environment, which gives you full control on the spacing between the alignment columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\bigskip
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\color{red}f:x^2+y^2 & =4, & \qquad\color{blue}f(3) & =2\\
\color{red}g:x^2-y^2 & =2, & \color{blue}g(4) & =1
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is that what You need?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\color{red}f:x^2+y^2=4,\qquad \textcolor{blue}{f(3)=2}\\
\color{red}g:x^2-y^2=2,\qquad \textcolor{blue}{g(4)=1}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's the reason for left alignment. Either you left align every display or none. Anyway, here's code for obtaining precise alignments.

I use `array` rather than `aligned` or variants thereon because it allows easier methods for setting colors and respect the spacings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{flalign*}% I see no reason for this...
  &% for flalign to work as wanted
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{
    >{\color{red}}r
    >{\color{red}{}}c<{{}}
    >{\color{red}}l
    @{\qquad}
    >{\color{blue}}r
    >{\color{blue}{}}c<{{}}
    >{\color{blue}}l
  }
  f &:& x^2+y^2=4, & f(3) &=& 2 \\
  g &:& x^2-y^2=2, & g(4) &=& 1
  \end{array}
  &% for flalign to work as wanted
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `flalign*`, which is quite a sledgehammer,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \hspace{0pt} % glue is needed at the beginning
  \begin{array}{
    >{\color{red}}r
    >{\color{red}{}}c<{{}}
    >{\color{red}}l
    @{\qquad}
    >{\color{blue}}r
    >{\color{blue}{}}c<{{}}
    >{\color{blue}}l
  }
  f &:& x^2+y^2=4, & f(3) &=& 2 \\
  g &:& x^2-y^2=2, & g(4) &=& 1
  \end{array}
  \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill} % pretend this is very wide, but shrinkable to fit
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course it's simpler if you don't need colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\[
\hspace{0pt}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  f &: x^2+y^2=4, &\qquad f(3) &= 2 \\
  g &: x^2-y^2=2, &\qquad g(4) &= 1
  \end{alignedat}
  \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\]

\end{document}
```